# What are the aliens species in the "Star Wars: The Force Awakens"?

Tags: star-wars, aliens, character-identification, the-force-awakens

We see many alien species in the "Star Wars: The Force Awakens", especially in Maz Kanata's castle:

[image]
*photo by Annie Leibovitz*

What species are they? Do all the species have a name? Is there a list of all alien species (along with their names) that we see in the "Star Wars: The Force Awakens"?

*Note:* Of course, there are the obvious ones we know from the previous movies.

Comment: Thank you for the photo. I believe the short alien with the pink snout and big bulging eyes in Warwick Davis's character in this movie, and this is the first picture I've seen of him to confirm by the description!

Comment: @DVK-in-exile: I was considering and you are really good at answering Star Wars questions :) Is it possible that you can include all the species in the movie but not only the ones we see at Maz Kanata's castle? So if we include "creatures" and "sentient species" in [this link](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary), does it cover all?

Answer (score 6):

Many (if not most) of them have names. They are listed in *[The Force Awakens: The Visual Dictionary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary)*, for example, in 'Castle Guests' section.

For example, the last square has `{{format: "name (species) - comment"}}`:

- Pru Sweevant (Narquois bandit) - the bluebeard.
- Captain Ithano aka Crimson Corsair. He's wearing red Kaleesh helmet but is a Delphidian species.
- Quiggold  (Gabdorin) - one legged pirate
- Strono Tuggs, also known as Cookie (Artiodac) - top center

Second square

- Wolliwan (Blarina) - front guy with big nose

First square:

- Praster Ommlen (Ottegan - similar to Ithorians) - the tall guy in back middle.
- ME-8D9 droid is part of castle's old time population.

Middle square:

- Grummgar and Bazine (Dowutin and Human) - the really big one and a black-hatted woman. SPOILER: she's a spy for First Order!
- Gwellis Bagnoro (Onodone) who looks like he has ant-eater nose, and his pet bartghest Izby.

---

- Another resource worth mentioning is Wookieepedia - people are fairly OCD about including that *Vanity Fair* article as a source, so simply search Wookieepedia for "Leibowitz" :)

  https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=%22Leibovitz%22+maz&fulltext=Search&ns0=1&ns14=1&ns112=1#
- One more curious resource may be LEGO sets. I saw one called 75139-battle-on-takodana mentioned.