# What intelligent species are common to both The Phantom Menace and A New Hope?

Tags: star-wars

Inspired by [Why are there so few familiar species in The Force Awakens?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113691/why-are-there-so-few-familiar-species-in-the-force-awakens)

Can someone list what intelligent species appear in both movies?

Obviously Gungans and Neimodeians are only in TPM, while humans and Hutts are in both.

But what about Aqualish and Devaronian - do we see any of them in TPM?

Comment: So you want two lists of species that comprehensively describe every species in each film, and another that highlights the overlaps?

Comment: And just these two film or prequels and sequels (not counting ep. VII). I think it would be shorter to provide species that were in both.

Comment: fair enough - i've limited the question to just common species between the two movies...

Comment: Question seems pretty broad. Would you like to narrow it down to *intelligent* species, or at least to *animal* species?

Comment: Well we have a wookie... Does that count?

Comment: Are there Hutts in A New Hope?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - yes, depending on which version you're watching...

Comment: @user14111 fair enough... I had not intended to include non-intelligent species, but happy to include the specification

Comment: Rodians https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgyyBLrYgC0

Comment: Correction - please list only intelligent species (coffee took a long time to take effect this morning)

Comment: Is there any way I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hutts (*Special Edition* only):

[image: Hutts 1]
[image: Hutts 2]

Humans:

[image: Humans 1]
[image: Humans 2]

Jawas:

[image: Jawas 1]
[image: Jawas 2]

Rodians:

[image: Rodians 1]
[image: Rodians 2]

Tusken Raiders/Sand People:

[image: Tusken Raiders 1]
[image: Tusken Raiders 2]

Wookiees:

[image: Wookiees 1]
[image: Wookiees 2]

Bith:

[image: Bith 1]
[image: Bith 2]

Aqualish:

[image: Aqualish 1]
[image: Aqualish]

Ithorians:

[image: Ithorians]

I can't find any good pictures, but there are apparently Ithorians in the senate scenes of *The Phantom Menace*.

Comment: would you mind only adding ones that aren't already listed? would you mind only adding ones that aren't already listed? (which I think would just be Hutts at this point)

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell I decided to do all of them, with pictures as evidence, to improve on existing answers. Is that ok?

Comment: That makes sense. My answer links to StarWars.com Databank which has the "Appearances" reference but I don't mind! Carry on!

Comment: What's wrong with the image of the [Ithorian senators](http://img.lum.dolimg.com/v1/images/databank_ithorian_01_169_5974636a.jpeg?region=0%2C0%2C1560%2C780) I found for you?

Comment: @RedCaio I wasn't sure it was from *TPM.*

Comment: @RogueJedi Oh. I guess it's _possible_ the image could be from Ep. 1, 2, or 3. Not 100% sure. Oh well. Enjoy the Wookiee image; I added the zoom and stuff myself. :)

Comment: @RedCaio my research turned up that the Ithorian image was from a cut scene of TPM so I wasn't going to include it either - but the StarWars.com Databank indicated that Ithorians were in TPM so I left it

Comment: The Aqualish senators kind of look like they're dancing.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like no Devaronians in TPM

**Aqualish**:
http://www.starwars.com/databank/po-nudo

**Ithorians**:
http://www.starwars.com/databank/ithorians

**Bith**:
http://www.starwars.com/databank/bith

**Wookiee**:
http://www.starwars.com/databank/wookiee

**Ronto**:
http://www.starwars.com/databank/ronto

**Dewback**: http://www.starwars.com/databank/dewback

For the sake of the list - (just hadn't got to it yet but credit to CBredlow for getting these first)

**Jawas**:
http://www.starwars.com/databank/jawa

**Tusken Raiders**:
http://www.starwars.com/databank/tusken-raiders

**Rodians**:
http://www.starwars.com/databank/rodian

**Bantha**: (suggested via comment)
http://www.starwars.com/databank/bantha

Comment: Didn't even think of the Ronto's or dewbacks

Comment: Banthas, weren't there a couple in the pod racing scene?

Comment: @CBredlow Banthas aren't intelligent.

Comment: @RogueJedi HorusKol stated in a comment that non-intelligent is ok for the list

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell - sorry - that comment was written in a pre-caffeinated state.. I meant to specify intelligent only... thanks for the additions, though

Answer (score 1):

Jawas, Tusken Raiders, Rodians, humans, as well as Ithorians and Aqualish (mentioned in a previous answer.