# Are there any "classic" species in Disney-era Star Wars movies?

Tags: star-wars

There are a lot of new aliens in the last three Star Wars movies, but very few known species from the Lucas's movies.

In Star Wars VII, we can see Admiral Ackbar (Mon Calamari), Nien Numb (Sullustan), Chewbacca (Wookiee). In Rogue One, we have Admiral Raddus (Mon Calamari) and an ugly twi'lek in Saw Guerrera's base. I don't think I've seen another alien coming from episodes I-VI.

In any of the Disney movies, are there any species present from the pre-Disney movies?

Humans don't count.

Comment: Humans. And no gungans. And no midichlorians. Those are main points.

Comment: Related 1: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113691/why-are-there-so-few-familiar-species-in-the-force-awakens?rq=1

Comment: Related 2: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111454/what-are-the-aliens-species-in-the-star-wars-the-force-awakens

Comment: Presumably the idea is that Disney won't get as much royalties off toys that are not their own IP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I cross-checked the Wookieepedia sentient species appearance lists of all the movies (including Rogue One and The Last Jedi), and looks like only the following ones have roles in both Lucas' and Disney's films (excluding Humans):

- **Aqualish**

  - Star Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace
  - Star Wars: Episode II Attack of the Clones
  - Star Wars: Episode IV A New Hope
  - Rogue One: A Star Wars Story
- **Dressellian**

  - Star Wars: Episode VI Return of the Jedi
  - Rogue One: A Star Wars Story (As a doll)
- **Kaleesh**

  - Star Wars: Episode III Revenge of the Sith (As a cyborg)
  - Star Wars: Episode VII The Force Awakens (Likeness represented by a mask only)
- **Mon Calamari**

  - Star Wars: Episode III Revenge of the Sith
  - Star Wars: Episode VI Return of the Jedi
  - Star Wars: Episode VII The Force Awakens
  - Star Wars: Episode VIII The Last Jedi
  - Rogue One: A Star Wars Story
- **Stennes Shifter**

  - Star Wars: Episode IV A New Hope
  - Star Wars: Episode VII The Force Awakens
- **Sullustan**

  - Star Wars: Episode II Attack of the Clones
  - Star Wars: Episode III Revenge of the Sith
  - Star Wars: Episode VI Return of the Jedi
  - Star Wars: Episode VII The Force Awakens
  - Star Wars: Episode VIII The Last Jedi
- **Twi'lek**

  - Star Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace
  - Star Wars: Episode II Attack of the Clones
  - Star Wars: Episode III Revenge of the Sith
  - Star Wars: Episode VI Return of the Jedi
  - Rogue One: A Star Wars Story
- **Wookiee**

  - Star Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace
  - Star Wars: Episode III Revenge of the Sith
  - Star Wars: Episode IV A New Hope
  - Star Wars: Episode V The Empire Strikes Back
  - Star Wars: Episode VI Return of the Jedi
  - Star Wars: Episode VII The Force Awakens
  - Star Wars: Episode VIII The Last Jedi
- **Yoda's species**

  - Star Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace
  - Star Wars: Episode II Attack of the Clones
  - Star Wars: Episode III Revenge of the Sith
  - Star Wars: Episode V The Empire Strikes Back
  - Star Wars: Episode VI Return of the Jedi
  - Star Wars: Episode VII The Force Awakens (Voice only, in vision to Rey)
  - Star Wars: Episode VIII The Last Jedi (As a ghost)

Comment: Oops... I had missed (the most obvious) one. Now fixed.

Answer (score 8):

With the release of *The Last Jedi* we have

> Yoda and [whatever his species is](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6199/where-is-the-rest-of-yodas-species)....

From *Rogue One* we have cameo by

> Ponda Baba, a male [Aqualish](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aqualish)